# Xamarin.Android In-App Billing OnProductPurchased not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have next code in my fragment (not all code, but general part):

```
public void BuySubscription(int number)
    {
        string vvalue = Security.Unify(
              new string[] {
                    SpecialStringOne,
                    SpecialStringTwo,
                    SpecialStringThree,
                    SpecialStringFour,
                    SpecialStringFive,
                    SpecialStringSix,
              new int[] { 3, 2, 0, 5, 1, 4 });

        _serviceConnection = new InAppBillingServiceConnection(Activity, vvalue);

        _serviceConnection.OnConnected += async () =>
        {
            await GetInventory();

            _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.OnProductPurchased += delegate
            {
                // Reaction if product was bought  
                ExtraTools.StringWorker.ShowMessage("I have bought it!", false);               
            };

            _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.BuyProduct(products[number]);
        };

        _serviceConnection.Connect();
    }
```

And I never get OnProductPurchased event.

This is general code inside MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Fragments.BillingFragment billingFragment = new Fragments.BillingFragment();
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (billingFragment != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Fragments.BillingFragment._serviceConnection.BillingHandler.HandleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                int code = data.GetIntExtra("ResponseCode", 2);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException exc)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Some error occurred", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

        }
    }
```

What is wrong inside fragment? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never thought that it can be reason of my problem, but when I removed **LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance** from my MainActivity, I have got demanded event.

It is very very strange!